# space between each row

Tags: html, css

I need to set background color to grey for each row with a space in between each row. My code below sets leaves no gap/space between the rows.

```
<table class="greydiag">
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.project)
                        {
                            @:<tr style="background-color:grey; margin-bottom:10px">
                            <td class="position">@item["position"]</td>                                
                            <td class="image">
                                <img src="@item["image"]" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="name">@item["name"]</td>

                            @:</tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property for the `table` as follows:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0 8px; /* two-value syntax: horizontal vertical */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/loleleti/1/edit)**.

**Note:** make sure the table has `border-collapse: separate;`.